# Show / Hide div depending on radio and checkbox buttons exclusively

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox, radio-button

In this page: http://www.metagame.gg/champions/ I have several filters to display or hide the pictures below.

I have already created a script to show/hide the divs depending on the selection of the first radio button (position). But I cannot figure out how to exclusively program the rest of the selectors (Radio buttons and checkbox).

The result of selecting different fields should be related by an **AND** condition.

In example: If I select Top and Tank and Melee, the displayed divs should be only the ones with the classes .top, .tank **and** .melee

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="selector">
<div id="selectorTitle">Champions filters</div>

<div id="selectorWrapperFirts">
    <div id="selectorSection">Position</div>
    <div id="selectorContent">
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input name="posi" type="radio" value=".top" /> Top</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input name="posi" type="radio" value=".jungle" /> Jungle</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input name="posi" type="radio" value=".mid" /> Mid</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input name="posi" type="radio" value=".bot" /> Bot</label></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="selectorWrapper">
    <div id="selectorSection">Role</div>
    <div id="selectorContent">
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input name="role" type="radio" value=".Assassin" /> Assassin</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input name="role" type="radio" value=".Fighter" /> Fighter</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input name="role" type="radio" value=".Marksman" /> Marksman</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input name="role" type="radio" value=".Mage" /> Mage</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input name="role" type="radio" value=".Support" /> Support</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input name="role" type="radio" value=".Tank" /> Tank</label></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="selectorWrapper">
    <div id="selectorSection">Damage Type</div>
    <div id="selectorContent">
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input name="dmg" type="radio" value=".AD" /> AD</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input name="dmg" type="radio" value=".AP" /> AP</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input name="dmg" type="radio" value=".Hybrid" /> Hybrid</label></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="selectorWrapper">
    <div id="selectorSection">Power Spike</div>
    <div id="selectorContent">
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input name="powers" type="radio" value=".egame" /> Early game</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input name="powers" type="radio" value=".mgame" /> Mid game</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input name="powers" type="radio" value=".lgame" /> Late game</label></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="selectorWrapper">
    <div id="selectorSection">Skill Ceiling</div>
    <div id="selectorContent">
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input name="skill" type="radio" value=".Low" /> Low</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input name="skill" type="radio" value=".Normal" /> Normal</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input name="skill" type="radio" value=".High" /> High</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input name="skill" type="radio" value=".Vhigh" /> Very High</label></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="selectorWrapperLast">
    <div id="selectorSection">Qualities</div>
    <div id="selectorContent">
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input type="checkbox" value=".Ranged" /> Ranged</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input type="checkbox" value=".Melee" /> Melee</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input type="checkbox" value=".Crowd-Control" /> Crowd Control</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input type="checkbox" value=".Engage" /> Engage</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input type="checkbox" value=".Disengage" /> Disengage</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input type="checkbox" value=".Counter-Engage" /> Counter engage</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input type="checkbox" value=".Jungle-Clear" /> Jungle clear</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input type="checkbox" value=".Burst" /> Burst</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input type="checkbox" value=".Peel" /> Peel</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input type="checkbox" value=".Poke" /> Poke</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input type="checkbox" value=".Scape" /> Scape</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input type="checkbox" value=".Siege" /> Siege</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input type="checkbox" value=".Splitpush" /> Splitpush</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input type="checkbox" value=".Sustain" /> Sustain</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input type="checkbox" value=".Teamfight" /> Teamfight</label></div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper"><label><input type="checkbox" value=".Wave-Clear" /> Wave clear</label></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="resetCheckboxesDiv">
    <button id="resetCheckboxes">Reset</button>
</div>
</div>
```

This is how the pictures HTML look. Notice the different classes that regulate the filters:

```
<div class="item  Melee Crowd-Control Engage  Counter-Engage Jungle-Clear Burst  Scape  Splitpush Sustain    Normal egame  Fighter    Tank Hybrid top jungle  ">
    <a href="aatrox">
        <img class="champavatar2" src="/icon/champions/aatrox.png" alt="">
        <div class="textavatar">Aatrox</div> 
    </a>
</div>

<div class="item Ranged  Crowd-Control Engage  Counter-Engage  Burst Poke Scape Siege  Sustain Teamfight Wave-Clear  High mgame Assassin   Mage   AP   mid ">
    <a href="ahri">
        <img class="champavatar2" src="/icon/champions/ahri.png" alt="">
        <div class="textavatar">Ahri</div> 
    </a>
</div>

<div class="item  Melee      Burst  Scape  Splitpush Sustain    Normal lgame Assassin Fighter     Hybrid top  mid ">
    <a href="akali">
        <img class="champavatar2" src="/icon/champions/akali.png" alt="">
        <div class="textavatar">Akali</div> 
    </a>
</div>

<div class="item  Melee Crowd-Control Engage Disengage Counter-Engage    Scape   Sustain Teamfight  Peel High lgame  Fighter   Support Tank AP    bot">
    <a href="alistar">
        <img class="champavatar2" src="/icon/champions/alistar.png" alt="">
        <div class="textavatar">Alistar</div> 
    </a>
</div>
```

Here is the JS that I managed to create for the first radio selector:

```
$('input[name=posi]').click(function() {
    if( $('input[name=posi]:checked').val() == '.top' ) {
        $('.top').show(); 
        $('.jungle').hide();   
        $('.mid').hide();   
        $('.bot').hide();   
    }
    else if ( $('input[name=posi]:checked').val() == '.jungle' ) {
        $('.top').hide();   
        $('.jungle').show();   
        $('.mid').hide();   
        $('.bot').hide();   
    }
    else if ( $('input[name=posi]:checked').val() == '.mid' ) {
        $('.top').hide();  
        $('.jungle').hide();   
        $('.mid').show();   
        $('.bot').hide();   
    }
    else if ( $('input[name=posi]:checked').val() == '.bot' ) {
        $('.top').hide();   
        $('.jungle').hide();   
        $('.mid').hide();   
        $('.bot').show();  
    }
});
```

I am a bit new to javascript so any help is highly appreciated.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Do you have the ability to change the HTML? It's not necessary, but jQuery works nicely with `data` attributes on HTML. You could select elements like `<div class="..." data-position="top" data-role="assassin" ...` and then select them with `$("div[data-position='assassin']").hide()`. It could simplify the answer a bit.

Comment: Yes, i can change the HTML easily

Comment: Nevermind my previous comment, smaili's solution is more simple than what I was thinking. To build up the `selected` string, you can use the `:checked` selector, `var selected = ""; $("input:checked").each(function(index, input) { selected += input.value; });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your situation, I would actually recommend making use of the [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) function.

So, what you'd want to do is create a list of all the selected radio's and their values separated by the `.` character - a notation for [multiple class selectors](http://quirksmode.org/css/selectors/multipleclasses.html).

So for your example, `If I select Top and Tank and Melee, the displayed divs should be only the ones with the classes .top, .tank and .melee`, your selector string would be `".top.tank.melee"`.

With that string, you could show those that match and hide those that don't:

```
var selected = ...;               // <-- for example, ".top.tank.melee"
$('.item').not(selected).hide();  // hide items not matching your classes
$('.item' + selected).show();     // show items matching your classes
```